# Graphic as clickable link without ERT

Tags: hyperref, lyx

In LyX, is it possible to make a graphic (e.g. PNG or PDF) a clickable link (URL) without the use of ERT?

Comment: I would be happy if I were wrong, but I don't currently think there is a way.

Comment: I want to amend my previous statement: you could create your own custom inset. See Help > Customization for this. However, that would require some work and I don't think it would be much smoother than ERT.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of. Even without making a custom inset. But you have to write the `\includegraphics[<options>]{/path/to/image}` manually.

- Choose Insert --> Hyperlink.
- Write the URL in the *Target* field, and `\includegraphics[<options>]{/path/to/image}` in the *Name* field.
- **Important**: check the *Literal* box.

  [image]

You won't see the image in LyX, but if you wrote the correct `\includegraphics`, you should see it in the PDF.

#### Note

If you haven't included other images via the LyX GUI, the `graphicx` package will not have been added, and then you need to go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

So technically this isn't using an ERT, though it probably isn't exactly what you were after either. Might be easier to write `\href{<url>}{` in one ERT, then insert the image via the LyX GUI, then write the closing `}` in a second ERT. Make sure to not add any space/line break/paragraph breaks between the ERTs and the image.